# progressbar labels can not be seen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have to fix a progressbar at work. Since I am quite new to coding I have one big problem. I am not able to display a message within the center of the progressbar.

This is the code for the progressbar:

```
progress: {
        show: function (msg) {
            notify.hideAll();
            var progress = $("<progress>");
            progress.attr("max", "100");
            progress.attr("value", "0");
            progress.attr("showText", "true");
            $(progress).append('<div id="progressLabel"></div>');
            $(sel(params.classNotifyBottomSmall)).find(sel(params.classNotifyButton)).hide();
            $(sel(params.classNotifyBottomSmall)).find(sel(params.classNotifyMsg)).html(progress);
            $(sel(params.classNotifyBottomSmall)).find(sel(params.classNotifyIcon)).hide();
            notify.glass.show();
            $(sel(params.classNotifyBottomSmall)).show();
            return progress;
        }
```

And this is a function to test the bar

```
setTimeout(function() {
        var progress = brmgui.notify.progress.show("Testfortschritt!");
        var pValue = 0;
        setInterval(function() {
            $(progress).attr("value", pValue);
            pValue++;
            $("#progressLabel").html("Wird geladen... " + (pValue-1) + "%");          
        }, 1000);
    }, 3000);
```

In the Google-Developer-Tools it looks like this:

[image]

But the label can not be seen within the bar. So i am quite clueless where my problem is.

The CSS of the label is simple:

```
#progressLabel{
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 30px;
            color: white;             
        }
```

So if anyone could help me I would highly appreciate it!

Comment: Could you provide a working snippet?

Comment: A fiddle would be helpful to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the label inside the `<progress>`, put it outside where `.progress-text` is the updating value.

```
<label>
  <progress value="50" max="100"></progress>Wird geladen...
  <span class="progress-text">50%</span>
</label>
```